# PYQT5 Dinamically assign Button to functions

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to assign different functions to the clicked signal of a button depending on the activated value of a combo box with PyQt5.

Here is how I am trying to do it:

```
self.filterComboBox.activated[int].connect(self.filterComboChange)

def filterComboChange(self,option):
        if(option==1):
            self.filterAddButton.clicked.connect(self.onClickFilterAddButtonAge)
        elif(option==2):
            self.filterAddButton.clicked.connect(self.onClickFilterAddButtonFormat)

def onClickFilterAddButtonAge(self):            
        #some lines of code

def onClickFilterAddButtonFormat(self):
        #some lines of code
```

I am selecting the first option in the combo Box, I push the button, function 1 runs fine
After that when I am pushing the button with the other option selected, before the second function being run, the first function runs.

Can anyone tell me the reason for this or tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If signal is already connected, you need to disconnect it first before connecting it again.

```py
def filterComboChange(self,option):
        try:
            self.filterAddButton.disconnect()
        except: 
            pass
        if(option==1):
            self.filterAddButton.clicked.connect(self.onClickFilterAddButtonAge)
        elif(option==2):
            self.filterAddButton.clicked.connect(self.onClickFilterAddButtonFormat)
```

Comment: I thought of that too but I couldn't find anywhere the disconnect function being used. It worked, thanks a lot!